# Adjust (crop) object on plane

Tags: modifiers

I'm still a beginner. Is there a way to use the sand surface as a boolean cutter to cut an object so that you pull the plane down onto the object and the plane doesn't just go through, but pushes/cuts the object away?

I'm trying to give the sand a kind of wall, but maybe there are easier ways.

[image: pic1] [image: pic2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **three options** you can use as a solution:

## Extrude the bottom of your sand plane and add a boolean

Select the outside *Edge Loop* of your plane by `Double Clicking` `Left Mouse Button` on the outside vertex or edge. (If it doesn't select the whole loop do this for all four sides by pressing `Shift` to keep the previous loop selected). Then Extrude down on the Z-Axis by pressing `E` then `Z` (to lock to Z-Axis) on your keyboard. Then once you have extruded to the bottom plane press `S` `Z` `0` to flatten it. Depending on which object you don't want to intersect to (if you don't want the sand to intersect with the bottom plane add the boolean modifier on the sand and vice versa if you don't want the bottom object to intersect with the sand) add a boolean modifier on the specific object of your choice (see my comment in the brackets) and set the specific object of your choice (see my comment in the brackets) as the *Target Object.*

[image]

## The Soldify Modifier

You can add a solidify modifier to your sand plane and play with the *Thickness* and *Offset* to get your desired result.[image][image]

If you don't want the objects to intersect, follow the same boolean procedure as above. Also, if you want to get the same solidify result, place the solidify modifer on the top in all of the modifier stack.

## The Boolean Modifier

You can add a boolean modifier on the bottom object, select the sand plane as the *Target Object,* and set the boolean to ***Intersect***.[image]

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @jayjo No problem! Have fun :)

Comment: Hey sorry, but could you please tell me how you made your sand so good or share your settings? But only if that's not too much work for you.

Comment: @jayjo I'd recommend you search up a few tutorials for materials and particles on YouTube. As to my setup, I simply subdivided my mesh many times in edit mode (or much easier than that is to use the subdivision surface modifier) and added a displacement modifier. Then I clicked the "**New**" button on the displacement modifier and went to the Texture Properties Tab (The one at the bottom of the side pane with a checkerboard texture) and switched my texture from image texture to "Clouds". You can play with the size of the texture and strength of the displacement modifier to get your result.

Comment: @jayjo To be honest, your sand looks pretty good... Check out these tutorials (or watch any of the thousands available on YouTube for free) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llRkz1gVz6U    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjM16FUMOKM    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=je8C03Yoc8A      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJAs395KaBU      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xM2Nz-A3UOk      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5ZvPMyQuy4     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCJVXkRCba0

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_wrSc8omoQ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EesfCLQD8jY&t=759s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7osHirLuMY https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdfjx5b9dzo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOXEMMSyZaY

Comment: @jayjo check the above tutorials out, I guess they will last you a week or two ;-)

Comment: thank you so much again <3

Comment: @jayjo No problem! Have fun ;)